# Mongoose connection issue with .env used into access

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am unable to pass requests with postman, and the error message is the one being printed on console. Before applying then method I was able to see the connection successful mssage but still wasn't able to get/post via postman

```
//database connection
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_URL,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(()=>{
    console.log("connection successful")
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Error occured on connection")
  });
```

Requiring the connection via

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

and the MONGO_URL mentioned in .env file is

```
MONGO_URL = mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.8noo9.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

been stuck here for a while. I am setting up mongoose for the first time

Comment: There's nothing in your code that implies you should be able to use Postman for anything.

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be a great idea to actually print the error that happens, not just `"Error occured on connection"`?

Comment: can you please mention how to add postman @AKX

Comment: There's no procedure to "add postman".

Comment: Well, your code seems to be working, because you're able to connect to the database.

Comment: Show the error in your question about the postman as support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to not whitelisting m IP. If anyone has the same issue try it first. Go to mongodb and whitelist your IP in security -> network connections